# How can I detect device-independent bitmap image in byte array?

Tags: c#, blob, binary-data, bmp

I am trying to retrieve files from MSSQL database which store files in image (datatype) format. I am streaming them as byte array and using magic numbers to detect the file formats. However magic number for BMP files is 0x424D  which is very common in random byte array (not related to .bmp files). I was wondering if there is any other signature that I can use for detecting bitmap images in binary data.

Comment: You can read whole header section and see if fields have sensible values...

Comment: I am not able to detect header section. It is third party application that has stored that data in database. So what I do is to detect header section by looking for the magic numbers for specific files. Additionally what do you mean by sensible values?

Comment: Jest read it as if it is bitmap header info. Than check if values of width/height/bit-per-pixel look reasonable (0< width < 10000,  0< height < 10000)  and checks out with overall size of the byte array. There is very little chance that random data/text will look like valid info.

Comment: Does the header contains all those info? I mean are they indicated right after 0x424D? Sorry I have never done these kind of conversions, so my questions may sound dumb. If those bytes are right after 424D, do you know how many bytes do I need to check  to be sure that it is actually bitmap image?

Comment: See eg [here](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch15b.htm) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)